# How to find program's Application Support folder

Tags: applescript

I am wondering if there is a way to get the name of a program's Application Support folder, perhaps in a way similar to get the id of an app.

```
osascript -e 'id of app "Sublime Text"'
```

gives you `com.sublimetext.3` which is the name of the Caches folder but the name of the Application Support folder is `Sublime Text 3`

Is there a way to do with osascript or something else?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, applications can name their Application Support folder whatever they want—there's no requirement that it be the name or bundle id of the app. Heck, there's also no requirement that it be stored in `~/Library/Application support`—an app could save all configuration data to your Desktop if it wanted to. Most Mac developers try to follow conventions, but I don't think there's a "rule" you can follow.

That said, one application that is surprisingly successful at finding these folders is [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). Intended to help you remove leftover files from an app you want to delete, AppCleaner also displays a list of these files prior to deletion:

[image: Screenshot]

What I will sometimes do is drag an app into AppCleaner, make note of the paths, and **click CANCEL** instead of delete.

Comment: I have come across AppCleaner in my searches but that doesn't address the question at hand.

Comment: @BuckDancer Why? I'm not suggesting you use it to actually delete anything—I'm suggesting you use the paths as a way to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Because using AppCleaner manual and I want to automate this with a script